# What does grep do?

Tags: command-line, xrandr, grep, find

Here is the description of `grep` from [GNU.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> `grep` searches input files for lines containing a match to a given pattern list. When it finds a match in a line, it copies the line to standard output (by default), or produces whatever other sort of output you have requested with options.

I have this command that I use often, which gives the name of the currently connected monitor:

```
xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
```

I can't see any files in this command, or links to them, so what exactly is going on? Is `grep` used for other stuff apart from searching files?

Comment: You told grep to find the output of the "connected" (with spaces, probably to ensure it only finds the correct line) from xrandr and awk to print the results. Err... I'm pretty sure that's what you did, at any rate.

Comment: You can find this and more in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-pipes-filters.htm

Comment: As an aside, you can get rid of `grep` and just have `awk` do the search itself with the following command: `xrandr | awk '/ connected / { print $1 }'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html) (emphasis mine):

```
grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines
containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the
matching lines.
```

And from [the GNU docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) (again, emphasis mine):

> #### 2.4 grep Programs
>
> `grep` searches the named input files for lines containing a match to
>   the given pattern. By default, grep prints the matching lines. A file
>   named `-` stands for standard input. **If no input is specified**,
>   `grep` searches he working directory `.` if given a command-line
>   option specifying recursion; otherwise, **`grep` searches standard
>   input**.

The standard input, in this  case, is the pipe connected to `xrandr`'s standard output.

The `grep` is superfluous in this case; `awk` can do the job by itself:

```
xrandr | awk '/ connected /{print $1}'
```

Comment: It should be noted that this mechanism of creating strings of small commands that can work on input via pipes is a key part of the unix philosophy, and extremely common in unix and linux.

Answer (score 10):

When you do:

```
xrandr | grep " connected "
```

you are basically redirecting the standard output (file descriptor 1, `/dev/stdout`) of `xrandr` to the standard input (file descriptor 0, `/dev/stdin`) of `grep`, this is the job of the pipe.

As `grep` takes input from standard input when no file name is given, your command will succeed as far as the file is concerned.

You can think of it as:

```
grep 'pattern' /dev/stdin
```

---

You can get the desired output with `grep` alone (no `awk` needed):

```
% xrandr | grep -Po '^[^ ]+(?= connected)'
LVDS1
```

This will get the first space separated word of the line (`^[^ ]+`) followed by a space and then the word `connected` (`(?= connected)` is a zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring `<space>connected` is matched after the desired portion).